# Not able to get correct value using models and list item in listview

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have one list view which contains multiple list items. Each list item has an edit or delete button but the problem is that when I click on any list item's edit or delete button it takes id or data of last list item. For example : i have 3 items say id 102, 104, 105 and if I want to edit id 102's data then it fetch data of last item and update it. I am not able to understand why it is not working perfectly.Code for adapter

// code

```
         @Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return 1;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {

    return this.addressModelList.size();
}





@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


 final   ViewHolder viewHolder;
    final  View result;


    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_show_all_address, parent, false);

        viewHolder.txtUserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        viewHolder.txtUser_phone =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_phone);
        viewHolder.txtLocation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        viewHolder.txt_edit_address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_edit_address);
        viewHolder.txt_deleteAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_deleteAddress);


        sp = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);


        addressModel = addressModelList.get(position);

        viewHolder.txtUserName.setText(sp.getString("firstName",null)+" "+sp.getString("lastName",null));
        viewHolder.txtUser_phone.setText(addressModel.getAddPhoneNumber() + "#" +addressModel.getAddressId()+"*" +position);
        viewHolder.txtLocation.setText(addressModel.getAddLocation());


        viewHolder.txt_edit_address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.e("TAG", "editAddress: "+addressModel.getAddressId() +"**" +position);

                showAllAddresses.editAddress(addressModel.getAddressId(),addressModel.getAddLocation(),addressModel.getAddPhoneNumber());

            }
        });


        viewHolder.txt_deleteAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showAllAddresses.deleteAddress(addressModel.getAddressId());
            }
        });




        result = convertView;
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }








  //  lastPosition = position;
    return convertView;
}
}
```

in edit or delete listener is takes first time right id then took value for last id.
please help

Answer (score 1):

get addressModel inside OnClickListener

```
      viewHolder.txt_edit_address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addressModel = addressModelList.get(position);
            Log.e("TAG", "editAddress: "+addressModel.getAddressId() +"**" +position);

            showAllAddresses.editAddress(addressModel.getAddressId(),addressModel.getAddLocation(),addressModel.getAddPhoneNumber());

        }
    });


    viewHolder.txt_deleteAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             addressModel = addressModelList.get(position);
            showAllAddresses.deleteAddress(addressModel.getAddressId());
        }
    });
```